# ¿Como puedo transformar este código Json a un objecto en Java para acceder a su información?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jackson

```
{"response":{"result":{"Tasks":{"row":{"no":"1","FL":[{"val":"ACTIVITYID","content":"2015459000001561025"},{"val":"SMOWNERID","content":"2015459000000100003"},{"val":"Task
   Owner","content":"(TI)
   Sistemas"},{"val":"Subject","content":"PruebaMisActividades"},{"val":"Status","content":"No
   iniciada"},{"val":"Priority","content":"Alta"},{"val":"SMCREATORID","content":"2015459000000100003"},{"val":"Created
   By","content":"(TI)
   Sistemas"},{"val":"MODIFIEDBY","content":"2015459000000100003"},{"val":"Modified
   By","content":"(TI) Sistemas"},{"val":"Created
   Time","content":"2017-02-21 10:00:11"},{"val":"Modified
   Time","content":"2017-02-21 10:00:11"},{"val":"Send Notification
   Email","content":"false"}]}}},"uri":"/crm/private/json/Tasks/getRecordById"}}
```

Comment: Hola William, ¿podrías compartir el código que llevas hasta el momento, e indicarnos en que punto tienes problemas?

Answer (score 3):

Podrias usar google-gson

https://github.com/google/gson

Exactamente lo que necesitas, la libreria tiene un metodo llamado fromJson(), el cual recibe el string como primer parametro que deseas convertir a objeto y como segundo parametro la clase a la cual deseas convertirlo.

Ejemplo:

```
public class JsonResponse{

    private JsonResult response;

    public JsonResult getResponse(){
        return response;
    }
}
```

este es tu objeto en el que convertiras el JSON al hacer un:

```
new Gson().fromJson("tu JSON String", JsonResponse.class);
```

para que sea efectivo debes de nombrar exactamente igual los atributos de tu clase como los del JSON, es por eso que se en el ejemplo use **private JsonResult response;** como atributo, ahora lo que debes hacer es crear cada uno de los objetos que necesitas, la clase que puse como ejemplo es solo el primer nivel de tu JSON, y debes crear un objeto por cada nivel que necesites, necesitas otra clase para "result", otra para "Tasks", otra para "row" etc. Y en cada clase que declares debes declarar los atributos de ese nivel, como por ejemplo en el nivel de results tienes un atributo "Tasks" y "uri", la uri debe ser de tipo string pero el atributo "Tasks" debe ser declarada como clase con el atributo "row" y asi, por ultimo los getters de cada clase te daran acceso a la informacion.

Espero haberme explicado, suerte.

Answer (score 2):

En Java puedes usar Jackson para esto. La forma de usarlo es muy fácil. Primero te tienes que crear una clase que represente la información que vas a recibir y luego deserializar la cadena:

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
MiClase miObjeto = jsonMapper.readValue(AQUI VA TU CADENA, MiClase.class);
```

Si quieres ver más ejemplos aquí tienes un enlace: [MkYong](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Espero que te sirva